# MySQL query with datetimestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have 7 rows in my table like "Date1","Date2"... they´re all dateTime, and i need to make a query to select the day, if is the today like: 
`"Select id,Date1 if Date1==today,Date2 if Date2==today etc..."`

the problem is i have the time wich can be any hour in the day,but wherever the time is e need to be based on the day, ignoring the time.

Theres a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to compare only the date values of the datetime fields:

> **DATE(expr)**
>
> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

```
SELECT DATE('2011-10-27 16:20:00'); # => 2011-10-27

SELECT id, Date1
    FROM ...
    WHERE DATE(Date1) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: CURDATE() cleaner over DATE(NOW())

Comment: Right, I was wondering if there was a better way.. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

DATE(Date1)=CURDATE() AND DATE(Date2)=CURDATE() etc.

But Date1,Date2 etc usually points to a poorly normalised db structure

Comment: You mean the nomenclature or the structure timestamp?

Comment: the nomenclature, unless 7 is set in stone often people do this rather than using rows in a joined table